# Narrow or widen type ? What to return in my public API

Tags: java, oop

Recently I Had conversation with my friend about good practices to create public API's We started to argue when we came to return types. He told me to return only widen type eg List insted of ArrayList. But in my opinion it all depend on problem we try to solve.
I see nothing wrong in:

ArrayList foo();

When I want to say "Hey I am giving You ArrayList just to assure that u got access to elements in O(1) time"

In next example lets assume that there is no inforamtion in method signature or documentation about what kind of graph is returned or what representation is used

Graph foo();

What now?  I might wonder whether this graph is directed or undirected , based on adjacency list or adjacency matrix. What is worst it could lead to code like:

```
Graph graph = foo();
if(graph instanceof DirectedGraph)
//code
```

which is a violation of Liskov substitution principle

What are your thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about why would you even expose an API and why should somebody use it? 
The most obvious reason would be to hide complexity of a problem (and solution) from the user of your API.

The user of your API doesn't want to concern himself with implementation details and underlying complexities you have abstracted away from him in the first place.

As an API provider, generally speaking, you don't want to limit yourself to concrete implementation such as the `ArrayList` in this example. Even if you should use `ArrayList` most of the time as `List` interface implementation, it wouldn't be impossible to get yourself in the situation that `LinkedList` would preform better.

This would break your existing API and clients would have to re-implement the change obviously. This is exactly what you don't want to do.

Take a look at [programming to interface](http://www.fatagnus.com/program-to-an-interface-not-an-implementation/) concept.

**Edit**

Whether you can put directed graph and a graph behind same interface will depend on your use case. What you could do most certainly however is to provide two interfaces, one for graph and the other for directed graph, protecting users of your API from future changes in implementations of these graphs.

User of your API should be able to specify what kind of graph he wants, directed or not, and you should be able to hide from him concrete graph implementation details.

Comment: Nice succinct answer. I would add that _sometimes_ Java Generics are good in situations like this (but obviously depends on the domain/context).

Answer (score 0):

> When I want to say "Hey I am giving You ArrayList just to assure that
>   u got access to elements in O(1) time"

Sounds like premature optimization.

> Graph foo();

A graph is always implicitly undirected. Digraphs are directed. I feel its abuse of terminology to refer to digraph as a graph unless you have made a clear distinction between an undirected and directed graphs -- in which case, I would have IGraph as an interface, and then have Digraph and Graph implement that interface.

From the point of view of using graph as a datatype (without behaviour), I see no problem in using a digraph as a graph -- It would simply ignore the order of its elements (edges and vertices). However, using a graph as a digraph might be problematic, as the order of elements might be random (should its elements be stored in a [bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)). That is, you can not be sure that elements are always returned in the same order, which does not make their order constant.

Answer (score 0):

> When I want to say "Hey I am giving You ArrayList just to assure that u got access to elements in O(1) time"

You must expose in your interface only what is needed, neither more nor less. So, in the case that you need to guarantee the access of O(1) it is right to use ArrayList, your implementation is not likely to change for that.

> Graph foo();

This implementation tells you that both kind of graphs can be returned, so it is up to you cast or check it as needed.

Don't do early optimization.

Answer (score 0):

> I see nothing wrong in:
>
> ```
> ArrayList foo();
> ```
>
> When I want to say "Hey I am giving You ArrayList just to assure that u got access to elements in O(1) time"

That's not the only thing you're saying when returning an ArrayList. What you're saying is: This method returns a very specific implementation of List: ArrayList and all overridings of this method must also return this very specific implementation, and nothing else.

There are several other implementations of List that are O(1) and are not ArrayList:

- the list returned by Arrays.asList()
- CopyOnWriteArrayList
- the list returned by Collections.emptyList() or Collections.singletonList()
- Any O(1) list wrapped into a Collections.synchronizedList() or Collections.unmodifiableList()
- ...

That constrains you, and constrains the subclasses (if the class is designed for subclassing) in a way that could make your code harder to evolve. And it doesn't bring much to the caller: the documentation can say that the list is RandomAccess, and the caller can make a copy if he really wants a non random-access list to be RandomAccess.

Regarding your second example, if types of Graphs have the same Graph interface, the caller shouldn't have to care about which concrete implementation is returned.

So, the rule could be: return the most precise interface that you can guarantee for now and the future, and for all the possible subclasses. But avoid returning a concrete implementation type when an interface type can do.

Of course, that really depends on the types at your disposal, on their design, and on the use-case. Design is more an art than a science.